# Spring Boot Microservices communication using Rest Template

Tags: spring, microservices

I am trying to implement to Rest Template to talk to another Microservice but it's not working properly, I am new to spring please help me complete this code.

```
@GetMapping("/name")
    public Product name(){//@PathVariable String name){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       Product x = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/products", Product.class);
       return x;
    }
```

> 2021-03-18 10:31:34.072 ERROR 56434 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while
> extracting response for type [class com.java.connect.entity.Product]
> and content type [application/json]; nested exception is
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
> `com.java.connect.entity.Product` out of START_ARRAY token; nested
> exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `com.java.connect.entity.Product` out of
> START_ARRAY token
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a single Product but an array of Products.

So you have to use

```
ResponsEntity<Product[]> response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/products", Product[].class);
Product[] products = response.getBody();
```

But I think this is not what you want and I assume that name would be a query parameter of the rest endpoint. So you have to pass name like this:

```
@GetMapping("/name")
public Product name(){@PathVariable String name){
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  Product x = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/products?name=" + name, Product.class);
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make below changes to get list of products using RestTemplate.

```
ResponseEntity<Product[]> response =
  restTemplate.getForEntity(
  "http://localhost:8080/products/",
  Product[].class);
Product [] products = response.getBody();
```